# Проблема с CMake! Не работает ни одна команда, вылезает ошибка "git не распознано как имя командлета...."

Tags: powershell

Пользуюсь PowerShell из VS версии 2022. Git на комп установлен версии 2.40.0
При вводе команды, к примеру "git init" появляется вот такое сообщение:

> git : Имя "git" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла
> сценария или     выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильн    ость
> написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего
> повторите     попытку.    строка:1 знак:1
>
> - git init
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Comment: Указывайте полный путь к исполняемому файлу git, например `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`.

Comment: Или добавьте путь к `git.exe` в системную переменную `PATH`